# Vue-Cookies: this.$cookies is undefined

Tags: cookies, vue.js

In my main component I have:

```
mounted() {
    window.$cookie.set('cookie_name', userName, expiringTime);
},
```

This yields the following error:

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of
>   undefined"

In my `main.js` I have:

```
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';
Vue.use(VueCookies);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use `window.$cookies` or `this.$cookies` (don't forget the s).

Answer (score -1):

as per today with the following requirements

```
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-cookie": "^1.1.4"
```

this syntax is correct

```
this.$cookie.set('cookie_name', userName, expiringTime);
```